# MongoDb C# Driver Projection after GroupBy with generic type

Tags: c#, mongodb

I've spotted an issue while working with mongodb c# driver (v 2.11.1)
I need to perform GroupBy and after select first id from each group.

When working on concrete IMongoQueryable it is working fine.
However when I wrapped it with some Generic helper class I got exception with unsupported method message.

here is code of dotnet core console application which shows the error. It looks like Select after groupby is not implemented for generic only for concrete.

```
using MongoDB.Driver;
using MongoDB.Driver.Linq;
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var sut = new Test<Quote>();

            var workingTest1 = sut.QueryableCollection.GroupBy(x => x._id).Select(x => x.First()._id).ToString();
            var workingTest2 = sut.TestCallWithCasting();

            var notWorkingTest = sut.TestCallWithoutCasting();
        }
    }

    public class Test<TEntity> where TEntity : IMongoDbEntity
    {
        private IMongoCollection<TEntity> _collection;
        public IMongoQueryable<TEntity> QueryableCollection => _collection.AsQueryable();
        public Test()
        {
            var client = new MongoClient();
            var database = client.GetDatabase("Quote");
            _collection = database.GetCollection<TEntity>("quotes");
        }
        public string TestCallWithCasting()
        {
            var t1 = ((IMongoQueryable<Quote>)QueryableCollection).GroupBy(x => x._id).Select(x => x.First()._id).ToString();
            return t1;
        }
        public string TestCallWithoutCasting()
        {
            try
            {
                return QueryableCollection.GroupBy(x => x._id).Select(x => x.First()._id).ToString();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return ex.Message;
            }
        }
    }

    public class Quote : IMongoDbEntity
    {
        public string _id { get; set; }
    }
    public interface IMongoDbEntity : IEntity
    {
        string _id { get; set; }
    }
    public interface IEntity
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `IMongoQueryable<T>` behaves differently if `T` is only known to be an interface. `TestCallWithoutCasting` doesn't throw exception if you add `class` before `IMongoDbEntity` in `TEntity : IMongoDbEntity`.

So finally it's like:

```
public class Test<TEntity> where TEntity : class, IMongoDbEntity
```